# Is the sinking liner in the Crimes of Grindelwald the Titanic?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

Is the sinking liner in the Crimes of Grindelwald the Titanic? If it is the liner, they got the weather all wrong because it was a starry night with calm waters, not the rough sea and lightning they showed.

Comment: In all probability the sinking ocean liner about 1901 as one answer says should put Harry Potter in an alternate universe where Muggle history has been different different than ours even if nothing else does.  It seems very improbable than an ocean liner looking similar enough to the one in the film to be it sank during the possible period of the film.  Thus it must be in an alternate universe with different muggle history and different ocean liners sinking.

Comment: @M.A.Golding I'm not following your logic at all.

Answer (score 26):

#### Almost certainly not.

Even though Leta's apparent age *could* set the year as 1912, there is no reason to believe that the ship was the *Titanic*. As you said, the weather is all wrong, and [Four-Funnel Liners](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Ships_with_4_funnels), while not common, were not unheard of. So it is likely that the ship, as far as the producers were concerned, was a period appropriate ship, and had no real-world correlation.

Additionally, JK Rowling’s [original screenplay](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Fantastic-Beasts-Grindelwald-Original-Screenplay/dp/1408711702) states that the sinking of the ship took place in 190**1**.

> INT. SHIP’S CORRIDOR—**1901**—NIGHT
> The door of the opposite cabin is ajar.

So at the very least, there appears to be no intention to connect the event to the sinking of the *Titanic* in 1912.

Comment: Ok thanks was not sure.

Comment: \*sigh\* Rowlingmaths strikes again. It couldn’t possibly have been 1901, at least not the way the film ended up turning out – that would have made Leta older than Dumbledore, which she obviously isn’t since he taught her at Hogwarts.

Comment: This is driving me nuts. I could have swore it was the Titanic... A ship that sank and was going from England to New York in the early 1900s....

Answer (score 3):

Looking at Leta’s age, it sure could be 1901, but certainly could not be 1912.

She was born between 1896-1898, as Newt's birth year according to [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/newt-scamander) is 1897, and they were in the same year at Hogwarts. We don’t know what time of the year either of them are born and so Leta’s birth year can’t be calculated exactly.

She’s obviously not a teenager at the time of the shipwreck. [Albus Dumbledore](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/albus-dumbledore) meanwhile was born in 1881 and is clearly older than both Newt and Leta.

Answer (score 3):

## No, it almost certainly isn’t the Titanic.

The theory that the ship Irma, Leta, and Corvus Jr. were on was the Titanic was directly addressed by the producer of Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald, David Heyman in an interview with the Pottermore News Team, where he said it was never discussed.

> **The mysterious ship is most likely not the Titanic**
>
> In one scene in the film, we see a flashback sequence with Leta Lestrange traveling on a ship with her brother – with tragic results when the ship begins to sink. Many fans have wondered if this is the famous sinking of the Titanic, which happened in 1912. David Heyman, however, disputed this.
>
> ‘It was never discussed,’ he told us. Although Callum Turner cheekily added, ‘I bet it could have been.'
>
> Mysterious! 
> <sub><sup>*[- 10 things we learned from The Crimes of Grindelwald cast and producer David Heyman (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/news/10-things-we-learned-from-the-crimes-of-grindelwald-cast-and-producer)*</sup></sub>

David Heyman said it was never discussed, so the movie therefore couldn’t have been made with the deliberate intent of the ship being the Titanic. Also, the Pottermore News Team concludes that the ship likely wasn’t the Titanic. Since Pottermore is officially affiliated with JKR, it’s unlikely they’d have inaccurate information on that, and furthermore, their reporting on Fantastic Beasts has been accurate so far. The year given in the screenplay for the screenplay was 1901, years before the Titanic sank, so the screenplay entirely contradicts that theory as well.

> **EXT. LIFEBOAT—1901—NIGHT**
>
> *CHILD LETA, IRMA, and BABY CREDENCE are in one boat, CREDENCE’S AUNT and BABY CORVUS in another.* 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald (The Original Screenplay)*</sup></sub>

It’s likely that the theory was addressed on Pottermore by David Heyman as a way of officially refuting it, since it makes no sense when also considering what’s already stated in the published screenplay.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was the Titanic at first, judging by interior etc, but if it had been 1912, then Corvus and the other child would only be 15 in the movies. Pretty sure Credence is meant to be older than that and it's him they're considering, after all.